# What makes a block a block

Tags: multivariate-analysis, bioinformatics, blocking

In multivariate analysis involve analysing different data sets of the same individuals, sometimes it is called integration or multi-block analysis.

However I can't find how are these dataset defined:

- in psychology each block seems to be a psychological test, and the multi-block analysis usually aims to find the common underlying variables explained by different tests (aiming to measure the same: p. ex. intelligence)
- in economics each block might represent economics, political and demographic variables

As  you might see, in these blocks sometimes there is a categorical variable

- in biology, with the new technologies enabling to measure thousand of gene expression and proteins. Which leads to recommendations like [these](https://doi.org/10.1093/bib/bbx060):

  > The variables that compose each block have to be defined carefully:
  >   not only according to their nature (e.g. one block that contains all
  >   the voxels of an image, one block for all the metabolites, etc.) but
  >   also according to external information. Nowadays, a huge amount of
  >   external information is available and can be used to define each
  >   block. For example, a block that contains all the metabolites can be
  >   divided into several data blocks; hence, metabolites belonging to one
  >   pathway are gathered within the same block. A block that contains all
  >   the voxels of an image can be grouped by regions: voxels belonging to
  >   one specific region are then gathered within the same block. This
  >   grouping strategy makes more interpretable blocks and facilitates the
  >   interpretation

I have problems following this advice. I have a block of gene expression, that I could divide by protein-coding and other type of genes, and within protein-coding I could divide them further by pathway. But a single gene might be related in several pathways, so I can't (without duplicating the information) create a new dataset for each pathway. In addition, it is not clear the definition of those pathways.

Following a tidy design I thought that each block should represent a group of variables that closely interact and might be intra-correlated. But I don't have any other reasoning than the multivariate variable must summarize the whole block in a single number

How are the blocks defined? Or how should I divide my blocks (If I should at all) ?

---

Note that this is different from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20806/105234) question as it is about grouping different variables and not samples.
Also is there a multi-block tag or related tag?